real solutions of a quadratic equation
I would like to study the quadratic equation
$$
p(x, y) = \sum_{1 \leq i < j \leq n} x_i y_j - x_j y_i = 0
$$
for vectors $x = (x_1, \ldots, x_n)$, $y = (y_1, \ldots, y_n)$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$. The equation may be written in the form
$\langle x, A y \rangle = 0$ (where $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ is the Euclidean scalar product), where the matrix $A$ is skew-symmetric with $1$'s above the diagonal.
The obvious solutions are: $x, y \in \ker A$ or $y = \lambda x$ (linearly dependent).

Are these the unique solutions?

For $n=2$, $p(x, y) = 0 \Leftrightarrow \mathrm{rank}\{x, y\} \leq 1$, which means that $x = 0$, $y = 0$, or $y = \lambda x$.
For $n = 3$, the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $-\lambda (\lambda^2+3)$, and $\ker A$ is $1$-dimensional, spanned by the vector $(1, -1, 1)$. The conclusion is similar.

What about $n \geq 4$? (solutions modulo $\ker A)$


It's easy to see that $\ker(A)$ has dimension $1$ when $n$ is odd and $0$ when $n$ is even.
In general, take any $y\in \mathbb{R}^n$. If $y\in \ker(A)$, then any $x$ satisfies $p(x,y)=0$. If $y\not\in \ker(A)$, then $Ay\neq 0$ so the set of $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $p(x,y)=0$ is just the hyperplane orthogonal to the vector $Ay$, and has dimension $n-1$.
So there are a lot more solutions than what you expected.

Thank you, indeed, this is the hyperplane orthogonal to $Ay$. Is it easy to see that $\ker A$ is $1$-dimensional when $n$ is odd and $0$ when $n$ is even. Since $A$ is skew-symmetric $\det A=0$ if $n$ is odd and $\ker A$ is not trivial...but how to compute the characteristic polynomial of $A$?

You don't have to compute the characteristic polynomial to see that a matrix is invertible. You can see that $\det(A)\neq 0$ when $n$ is even, for instance because $\det(A)$ is an odd number. You could compute the determinant modulo 2, maybe recursively, or you can easily see that $A^2=I_n$ modulo $2$, so the determinant is non-zero mod $2$.
